# Issue with a python string loop

Tags: python

So I'm having trouble getting my code to use a list of strings as inputs in a loop. Here's roughly what I have so far.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

Users = ['User01','User02','User03']
User_string = str(Users) # Have to do this as code needs input as string
gis = GIS("https://www.arcgis.com","USERNAME","PASSWORD") # This logs you into ArcGIS Online
User_role = 'org_user'

for x in User_string:
    test = gis.users.get(username=x)
    test.update_role(role=User_role)
  print("Done! Check Web")
```

I just can't get the loop to work right. When I remove the for loop and put each user name in individually the get user and update role commands work just fine, it's just in the loop that is broken.

The two errors I'm getting is that the username has to be a string. I fixed that by adding the str() command, but I can't get the username to enter into the user.get loop.

Any suggestions? This code is actually looking at an excel file to produce the list of usernames so I can't just hardcode the list into the code. If it helps at all the website I've been using for the ArcGIS portion of the code is this one: https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/accessing-and-managing-users/

I should mention that I also tried just printing

```
test=gis.users.get(username=User_string)
```

And it came back as None. So I guess my question is how do I get 'User01' to go into the username=x spot?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a for with the list as a string so it's looping on each character of the string. You need to do it with the original list.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I just tried it again with the list instead of the string to get the exact error message and this time it went through. I have no idea why. But it works now! Thank you for helping an idiot!

Comment: It's because your were iterations each character when you turned the whole list to a string. >>> Users = ['User01','User02','User03']
>>> User_string = str(Users)
>>> User_string 
"['User01', 'User02', 'User03']"
>>> for u in User_string:
...     print(u)
... 
[
'
U
s
e
r
0
1
'
,
 
'
U
s
e
r
0
2
'
,
 
'
U
s
e
r
0
3
'
]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you are telling your `for` loop to iterate on a `String`, since you converted your list to a string with `User_string = str(Users)`; So the loop is going over each character on the string, which now it is `User01User02User03`

What you need to do is to iterate the list `Users`, like:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

Users = ['User01','User02','User03']
gis = GIS("https://www.arcgis.com","USERNAME","PASSWORD") # This logs you into ArcGIS Online
User_role = 'org_user'

for x in Users:
    test = gis.users.get(username=x)
    test.update_role(role=User_role)
  print("Done! Check Web")
```